# How to delete the previous output in perl CGI script?

Tags: html, perl

My HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>hello</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor = pink>
<form action ="hai.pl" method=post>
<label>enter your name</label>
<input type = "text" name ="fname">
<input type = "submit" value = "go">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

perl script

```
use CGI ':standard';
$firstname = param('fname');
print "<html>";
print "<head>";
print "<title>$firstname</title>";
print "</head>";
print "<body>";
print "<h2> hai $firstname </h2>";
print "</body>";
print "</html>";
```

When i give the first input into the html code that only print the many more times of the output but different kind of input. example
first time i give the input MKHUSSAIN . which output is hai MKHUSSAIN . next time i give the input BOXER. which output is hai MKHUSSAIN. how can i clear this error?

Comment: It sounds like your browser is caching the output of your perl script, and that may be why you are seeing previous output from the script on subsequent runs. Try placing the following line at the top of your perl script, and see if this solves the problem:   print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

Comment: print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"; This is not working. Same mistake rises on the outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should only print out an error.  There are a few things wrong with your perl script.  First you need a shebang to indicate which interpreter will be running the file.  Second you need to print a cgi prefix (the header function below) to indicate the type of content for the page.

You should also include error and warnings support for your perl script.  This will help you to easier identify problems.

Look at:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strick;    
use warnings;
use CGI ':standard';

my $firstname = param('fname') || "";

print header;

print "<html>";
print "<head>";
print "<title>$firstname</title>";
print "</head>";
print "<body>";
print "<h2> hai $firstname </h2>";
print "</body>";
print "</html>";
```

Again, the example you posted wouldn't do anything but show errors.  The changes I made actually does what you described as your objective.

Answer (score 0):

Make that param line into a two part thing.

```
my $firstname="";  
$firstname= $cgi->param("fname");
```

Creating a empty string first also helps to empty it, everytime it is run. This is also a security conscious move.

Answer (score 0):

```
use CGI;
$cgi = CGI->new();
$firstname = $cgi->param('fname');
print "<html>";
print "<head>";
print "<title>$firstname</title>";
print "</head>";
print "<body>";
print "<h2> hai $firstname </h2>";
print "</body>";
print "</html>";
```

use the 'CGI->new()' in every perl script then only execute the output which we expect.